# Code in post renders differently in normal view vs. edit view - and normal view looks wrong

Tags: bug

This example is using: [Mercurial Fails to Update to A Revision Due to a File Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258961/mercurial-fails-to-update-to-a-revision-due-to-a-file-name)

The normal view shows the code lines all broken up, extra lines, etc. But in edit mode it basically looks like what I would expect.

I'm not sure if this is new, normally I thought both views looked the same all the time. At least I've never noticed this before.

**Normal view:**

[image]

**Editing view:**

[image]

---

**Update** - I did edit that question to fix the readability. All that was needed was to remove the  triple backtick style of formatting and use the spaced indentation for the code blocks. So I guess it was the triple backticks that are not rendering consistently.

Comment: It looks good to me. Perhaps because of your edit?

Comment: @Glorfindel oh, yes I did complete my edit after posting this. Maybe I should have waited...

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs A side note: Rather use multiline code formatting (i.e. indent each line with four spaces), rather than inline code formatting (each line enclosed with backticks).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ normally I just click the toolbar button and let it do its thing